# Share location on android share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, geolocation, location, share

I want to share a location attached to my share intent. Is it possible?

Something like this, but adding location information:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The status update text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Dialog title text"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to share? To mail or somewhat?

Comment: you might put everything that implements Parcelable

Comment: check this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your location data as part of the text of the message, in `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Or, you are welcome to invent a new extra (e.g., `EXTRA_LOCATION`), put the location data in there, and then convince all the world's Android developers to use it where relevant when they implement activities that respond to `ACTION_SEND`.

But, beyond those two choices, `ACTION_SEND` does not support anything else related to location.